# full outer join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

There are two tables tableA and table B
both the tables have common column id

We want to get the results which are having all records in A but not in B 
and all records which exists in B but not in A

Regards,
Chinta kiran

Comment: Okay, so what did you try, and what "didn't work"?

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+full+outer+join

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for MINUS SET OPERATOR:

*"We want to get the results which are having all records in A but not in B"*

Easy way:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A 
WHERE A.id not in (SELECT id FROM B)
```

With Full Outer Join

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A full outer join B on A.id = B.id
WHERE B.id is Null
```

The right way:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A left outer join B on A.id = B.id
WHERE B.id is Null
```

Change A to B and B to A for in order to get the results which are having all records in B but not in A.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the article [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) by Jeff Atwood of Coding Horror.

> Full outer join produces the set of all records in Table A and Table B, with matching records from both sides where available. *If there is no match, the missing side will contain null.*

Comment: Aww, I was sure the name spelling was intentional..

Comment: Both first and last were off, but in ways that were still words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION operator as follow 
`SELECT * FROM tablea
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableb`
if you want to read more about
[UNION operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is best accomplished with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` where the predicate (`WHERE` clause) ensures that the joined row is NULL; something like:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id WHERE B.a_id IS NULL;
```